# No known class method for selector error in RNFirebaseAuth.m file when run ios build

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

No known class method for selector 'credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:rawNonce:'

try every solutions pod update,pod install , cocopods update & install, pod repo update but same error....